# What is the scope of Firebase security rules variables?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is that ok in Firebase to use the same variable name multiple times, e.g. `$itemId` here:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
      "$itemId": {                             // first time
        ".write": "$itemId == 1"
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        "items": {
          "$itemId": {                         // second time
            ".write": "$itemId == 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do variables have scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, [security rules cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide.html#section-cascade). The variables only apply to the block `{...}` under which they are declared. They are applicable to all of the children of that block.

```
{
  "rules": {
     "$level1": {
        "$level2": {
           "bar": {
               ".validate": "..." // $level1, $level2 are both usable here
           }
        }
     }
     "pathb": {
        ".validate": "..." // here $level1 is undefined
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: So this means that it is perfectly ok to use the same variable name multiple times, like in my example, right?